# При переходе на другую страницу не меняется url

Tags: php

Сайт написан на php. Каждая страница включает в себя футер и хеадер, которые подключаются через include. При переходе по страницам не меняется url. если в вручную к url сайта дописываю путь к файлу, то все-равно попадаю на главную страницу. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Покажите Ваш код

Comment: К сожалению сейчас могу поделиться файлами только с яндекс диска. https://yadi.sk/d/9g3FHBZ_pskZo

Comment: может быть проблема в .htaccess?